# CompareTo(Object o) used to compare strings in java

Tags: java, string, object, compareto

In my program I'm trying to compare names by last name, and if those are the same then compare by using the first name. However, I can't quite figure out how to compare the strings.

Can someone help me out with this?

```
public class Student implements IComparable
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
int score;

public Student()
{

}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void getLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void getScore(int score)
{
    this.score = score;
}
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
   //Compares Student objects by last name. If the last names are the same 
   //it compares by first name.
    Student s = (Student) o;

    if (this.getLastName().toUpperCase() < s.getLastName().toUpperCase())
        return -1;
    else if (this.getLastName().toUpperCase() > s.getLastName().toUpperCase())
        return 1;
    else
    {
        if(this.getFirstName().toUpperCase( < s.getFirstName().toUpperCase()
            return -1;
        else if (this.getFirstName().toUpperCase( > s.getFirstName().toUpperCase()
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is `IComparable`? In Java, `Comparable` is generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't make things more complicated:

- `String` class already provides `compareToIgnoreCase` method
- value returned by compare methods of `String` is already good to be directly returned

Basically the same functionality could be expressed with:

```
int compare = getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getLastName());
return compare == 0 ? getFirstName().compareToIgnoreCase(o.getFirstName()) : compare;
```

Mind that you need to check that `o instanceof Student` if you have an `Object` argument.

I don't get why you are using a custom `IComparable` interface, which sounds much like the one provided in C#, since Java provides `Comparable<T>` which is generic and doesn't require checking for the runtime type of the argument (since it's not `Object` anymore but `T`).

Comment: instanceof already do the null check and returns false if it's null

Comment: If you check `o instanceof Student`, you don't also need to check `o != null`, since `instanceof` always returns `false` for a `null`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot. I was over complicated things because I forgot strings could be compared that way.